# Глагол "почтить": можно ли почтить кого-что, не сообщая, чем?

Tags: управление

> Большой толковый словарь
>
> [**ПОЧТИТЬ**](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C)
>
> ---

У меня - начало главы, то есть контекста кот наплакал:

> Соблюдая традиции, мы немедля **почтили дом и его гостеприимных
>   хозяек** – ещё стоя выпили забористой сливовицы, после чего
>   сопровождающие бесшумно исчезли, словно растворились в полумраке
>   тихого дома.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Соблюдая традиции, мы немедля почтили дом и его гостеприимных хозяек – ещё стоя выпили забористой сливовицы, после чего сопровождающие бесшумно исчезли, словно растворились в полумраке тихого дома.*

Можно почтить ***чем и как*** (почтить вставанием). Обособленный оборот отвечает на вопрос ***почтили как***.

Также *чем почтили* может быть ясно из контекста, например:

Предисловие написал пятидесятилетний Сергей Ошеров, послесловие ― семидесятипятилетний Вильгельм Левик. Среднее и старшее поколения признанных переводчиков **почтили таким образом**, можно сказать, Мафусаила отечественного художественного перевода.  [Вадим Перельмутер. Записки без комментариев (2001-2003) // «Октябрь», 2003]

Answer (score 0):

Можно, конечно.
Вообще не вижу причин так ставить вопрос. 
Даже Кузнецов по вашей ссылке дает вариант: "П. мужество павших".

Другое дело, что тут стилистически "почтить" не всем понравится.